# getting nil:NilClass when scoping dates in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, scoping

I'm a bit dumfounded - getting an 'undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass' error.

I've created a pretty straight-forward scope in the model

```
  def self.just_added
      where('created_at > ?', Time.now-7.days.ago).order("created_at desc").first(4)
  end
```

And a loop in my view

```
<% @just_added_jobs.each do |job| %>
    <%= link_to job.name, job %>         
<% end %>
```

Not sure what's going on - I'm fairly certian I've created a scope like before that worked fine.

Also - I also plan to do some more complex scoping with dates - I have several date fields as part of a model (i.e., to loop through the jobs that are due soon, past due). Where could I read more about scoping dates?

Comment: are you initializing @just_added_jobs in your controller?

Comment: Nope, sigh. I knew I forgot something simple. Works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The result of the classmethod you show can never be `nil` so we must conclude you're failing to set `@just_added_jobs` in the controller.
2. `created_at > Time.now-7.days.ago` makes no sense, you probably mean `created_at > 7.days.ago`
3. Calling `first(n)` on a scope is a bad idea because the result is not a scope anymore but an array. You need `limit(n)`.

Comment: Yep, forgot to add to controller. The tip on .limit - that makes more sense.

Comment: “Can't never” seems like it has one too many negatives in it.

Comment: @Andrew: I cannot say that I do not disagree with you ;-)